# angularjs - how to get files attribute in input tag without using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, file-upload, ng-file-upload

I'm Uploading files with AngularJS.
How to get the input files just like regular JS?

**This is what I need to simulate exactly**
HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileImg" accept="image/*">
```

JS:

```
var filesUpload = document.getElementById("fileImg").files
```

**This is what I have now**
HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" ng-model="image" accept="image/*">
<input type="button" ng-click="submit()" value="press me">
```

Angular:

```
angular
        .module('app')
        .controller("productsCtrl", function($scope) {

            $scope.image = {};


            $scope.submit = function() {

                var filesUpload = ????????????????
            }
         }
```

So, how to get the "files" in the input withput using "getElementById" ?
notice - can't change nothing , only the "??????"

any help will be appreciated..
tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom directive

```
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Main', function($scope, $timeout, $rootScope){
    $scope.onSubmit = function(){
        console.log($scope.file);
    }
});

app.directive('fileRead', [function () {
    return {
       scope: {
        fileRead: '='
       },
       link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
           elem.bind('change', function (event) {
             scope.$apply(function () {
                scope.fileRead = event.target.files[0];
             });
           });
       }
    }
 }]);
```

usage

```
 <div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="Main">
        <form ng-submit="onSubmit()">
            <input type="file" name="someName" file-read="file">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: sadly i can't use a directive. bummer, i know. thank anyway dude.

Comment: This is a nice solution, if you don't want to use directive, you can add some id to your input field, then in submit handler get files in this way .

`var fileElement = document.getElementById('file');`
`var files = fileElement.files;`

Comment: it's a Constraint, not a wish of mine.

Comment: and ya the one with the ID , is not possible at this time.